# Searching for a Prolog predicate

Tags: prolog

I need a predicate in Prolog, that produces progression like:

[0, 0.1, 0.2 , 0.3, ..., defined end].

I only know the built-in between/3, but that produces only integers like 0,1,2,3...

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a reduction to between (no error checking and it may have some precision errors for some floating point numbers):

```
between_step(First, Last, Step, Var) :-
   NrSteps is integer((Last - First) / Step),
   between(0, NrSteps, TempVar),
   Var is First + Step * TempVar.
```

Some usage examples:

```
?- between_step(2.5, 3, 0.1, X).
X = 2.5 ?;
X = 2.6 ?;
X = 2.7 ?;
X = 2.8 ?;
X = 2.9 ?;
X = 3.0

?- findall(X, between_step(0, 1, 0.1, X), Xs).
Xs = [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]
yes
```

Comment: Mh, if I call "findall(X, between_step(0, 10, 0.1, X), Xs)", I get the solution: Xs = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6000000000000001, 0.7000000000000001, 0.8|. Any suggestions to fix it?!

Comment: Are you talking about 0.30000000000000004 instead of 0.3?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I didn't mentioned it.

Comment: That's because floating point numbers are inexact. But many Prolog systems try to correct this when displaying results. In B-Prolog and SWI Prolog I get "..., 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, ..." with your query. What Prolog system and version are you using?

Comment: Mh, how can I get the version of my Prolog? Is there any predicate for? Couldn't find something like that.. :/ I'm using SWI-Prolog for Mac OS X.

Comment: I'm on Linux and I can just run swipl on the command line and it will tell the version right after loading.

Comment: How do use the result of the predicate? Do you want to print it or pass to other predicate? Try "findall(X, (between_step(0, 10, 0.1, X)), Xs), writeln(Xs)." Are numbers rounded in the  printed version of the Xs?

Comment: Hey Sergey! I'm using version 6.2.6. Yes, I want to pass it to another predicate: I want to call the same (research) predicate with other parameters. One time with the value 0.1, then 0.2 and so on. If I call your code, I get the following: "?- findall(X, (between_step(0, 10, 0.1, X)), Xs), writeln(Xs).
[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.30000000000000004,0.4,0.5,0.6000000000000001,0.7000000000000001,....." Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following, but if you ask me, constructs that mimic a procedural looping via backtracking are something of a Prolog [*code smell*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), indicating that your design has an impedance mismatch with the way Prolog works.

```
for(From,To,Step,From) :- % Unify the incremental value with the current 'From' 
  Step >  0  ,            % - when the 'Step' is positive, and
  From =< To .            % - the 'To' limit has not been exceeded.
for(From,To,Step,Inc) :-  % On backtracking...
  Step > 0          ,     % - when the 'Step' is positive, 
  From < To         ,     % - and the 'To' limit has not yet been reached
  Next is From+Step ,     % - increment 'From'
  for(Next,To,Step,Inc) . % - and recurse down.  
for(From,To,Step,From) :- % Unify the incremental value with the current 'From'
  Step < 0 ,              % - when the 'Step' is negative, and
  From >= To .            % - the 'To' limit has not been exceeded
for(From,To,Step,Inc) :-  % On backtracking...
  Step < 0          ,     % - when the 'Step' is negative, and
  From > To         ,     % - the 'To' limit has not yet been reached
  Next is From+Step ,     % - decrement 'From'
  for(Next,To,Step,Inc) . % - and recurse down
```